# How to enable group font in a protected sheet using WorksheetBase.Protect

Tags: vsto

I have the need to unblock the group font on a protected sheet How can I do that I have the following code

Sheet.Protect(password: "Trial", drawingObjects: true, contents: true, scenarios: true, allowFiltering: true, allowFormattingRows: true, allowFormattingColumns: true, allowInsertingRows: true, userInterfaceOnly: true);

This way I protected, but I have the need to enable just the group font 
how can i do this?

I've tried disable each parameter having not success.